# Algorithm used in scipy.spatial.Delaunay for Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy, triangulation, delaunay

In my Python code I use [scipy.spatial.Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) to obtain a Delaunay triangulation. I can't figure out, but I'm really curious, which algorithm is used in this function in order to create the Delaunay triangulation. Does anyone know?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888546/regularly-spaced-orthogonal-grid-delaunay-triangulation-computing-the-paraboloi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regularly spaced orthogonal grid Delaunay triangulation (Computing the paraboloid coeficients)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888546/regularly-spaced-orthogonal-grid-delaunay-triangulation-computing-the-paraboloi)

Answer (score 1):

As the doc states

> The tesselation is computed using the Qhull library [Qhull].

Since `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` uses the `Qt` paramter for Qhull, [this](http://www.qhull.org/html/qdelaun.htm) is used and there it states

> The Delaunay triangulation is the triangulation with empty
>   circumspheres. It has many useful properties and applications. See the
>   survey article by Aurenhammer ['91] and the detailed introduction by
>   O'Rourke ['94]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that "Qhull computes the Delaunay triangulation by computing a convex hull." I just still don't find a description or name of an algorithm used, of how these convex hulls are computed and how the Delaunay triangulation is computed from that?

Comment: The keyword is  `empty circumspheres`. You can further look for that or take a look at the publications mentioned above.